# How to prepend all the output of tar -tf

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I can execute

```
tar -tf example.tar
```

I get a list of all files of the tarball

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
subdir1/file1.txt
```

What I want is to store all these files into text file with a root path before each file name. E.g.

```
/rootdir/file1.txt
/rootdir/file2.txt
/rootdir/subdir1/file1.txt
```

Comment: `tar tf exaple.tar | sed 's,^,/root/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tar -tf example.tar | sed -e 's!^!/rootdir/!'
```

Answer (score 3):

Something simple with `sed`?

```
tar tf example.tar | sed 's#^#/rootdir/#' >file.txt
```